# Rename part of png file names based on a string in a txt file

Tags: file, rename

I need to rename png files using a string contained in a txt file.

I have png files named like (the only words that change are the sizes):

> Event_Post_260x200_CITY.png

and 1 txt file in which I have written:

> Place_Event,Date_Event
>
> Test,10 September 2018.

The txt file has this formatting because I use a script in Photoshop.

How can I rename the png files using the txt file like:

> Event_Post_260x200_Test.png

I tried different ways but I am not able to achieve that.

I'm working on Windows 10.

Thank you for your help.

```
@powershell -command get-childitem *.png | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("CITY", "TEST") }
```

Comment: where is your code? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is **How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**.

Comment: Sorry, I've added it.

I don't know how to refere to a string that it's in a txt file.

Comment: Nice to see formatting and content improvements. The task you have to perform is easily done in python... however, you then need to have either knowledge of that language or learn it. Perhaps its a good idea to tell people on which platform you're working.. windows, linux.. or macOS. That way a small script can be made to do the job. The latter two have by default python installed.

Comment: I'm working on Windows 10.

Comment: then get yourself python installed. I'll answer with a python script in a few minutes to do that job for you in a blink of an eye. See [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.4/python-3.6.4.exe) for x64 and lastest version.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "png", or "photoshop". Removing tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job for you when you got python installed. Inline there are comments for you where you can change things. There is also explenation what the code does for you at that particular point.

Copy the code to a filename.py and run it from the command-line.

...from command-line: `python remane_filenames.py`

1. File can be opened with notepad and from an editor like IDLE or Komodo edit.
2. Variables can be edited by you to change city, date, event_place/name, etc.
3. Select my answer and vote on it so my effort is not pure getting the dust from sunk-away-code .

Enjoy conversion ;-)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# remane_filenames.py

import os, shutil

print os.path.realpath(__file__)      # path where file.py is executed from.

myfilelist = os.listdir('.')           # creates filelist. The '.' can be another folder.
destfolder = "D:\output"               # target folder (may created automatically.
ftype      = 'png'

# variables you can change yourself 
Place_event = 'Windmils'
Date_event  = '2018-01-26'
City        = None

# main code:

for scr in myfilelist:                # steps through a list of files.

    if os.path.isfile(scr) == True:   # checks if file is file and not a folder.

#        print item                    # shows the filename on which we work.

        myfile = scr.split('.')

        if myfile[1] == ftype:         # correct filetype?

            try:
                event, post, size, city = myfile[0].split("_")

                print event, post, size, city

                if City == None:

                    City = city            #use default cityname

                filename = Place_event + '_' + post + '_' + Date_event + '_' + size + '_' + City + "." + ftype

                print filename

                dest = os.path.join(destfolder, filename)

                print dest

                # if the folder doesn't exist..create it.
                if os.path.isdir(destfolder) == False:
                    os.mkdir(destfolder)

                shutil.copy2(scr, dest)

            except Exception as e:
#                print e                # print line for debugging code to see if something is not working.
                continue
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you missed the point or I didn't explain myself well.


I need the png files to be renamed using the text that is already in the .txt file.


I don't want to write again the Place event (The only value I'm interested in this operation); I want the script to automatically rename the png file after it has taken the value (place event) from the txt file already compiled.

Comment: For now replace in the script "Windmills" by the event-location where you shot these pics as to do for date-event. No import from text-file needed. I'll update the script later today to handle that. It's just plain code as you put in your question..right? I'm going to use this as an example to compile it to an standalone exe-file and use the textfile as "data input". Then there is no need to install python and know how it works.

Comment: When done I'll post a wetransfer so you can download it from there. But what I need to know is where you want targetfolder?

Comment: Oh ok thank you! My folder path (where I have the images and the txt file) is E:\Downloads\Gabriele\Facebook Imgs

Comment: I've made it into an installer application with option to put a short-cut link on the desktop. Let me know if it works. The link I'll provide expires in a few days, which I will remove once you got the program.

Comment: and removed the link.

Comment: @TheSylar...  BTW... check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on how you can reward m aside some feedback; would be great to hear something after working on it for two days.

Comment: if the person who downvoted a second ago can leave a comment.. that would be appreciated!