# How come freshly Inno Setup baked exe-file request contact with MS if compiled script lacks such instructions

Tags: windows, python-2.7, inno-setup

I'm kinda baffled why my freshly baked exe-file is requesting to contact **IP 131.253.61.96**; which Whois shows its from Microsoft company. This particular behavior was detected by the installed firewall who threw a "repeat program" alarm and got me intrigued.
How do you know? Well because I did not compile such instructions into the exe-file with my script posted nor with the Inno Setup spec-file (`Inno Setup v5.5.9(a)`).

My code is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48463787/8928024) as answer on the SO [question **"Rename part of png file names based on a string in a txt file"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48460078/rename-part-of-png-file-names-based-on-a-string-in-a-txt-file/48463787#comment83923694_48463787).

Any background on why and how this behavior occurs and most important **how to prevent** it (aside instructing the 3rd party firewall to block outgoing traffic for this particular exe-file) is more than welcome.

Comment: Is your installer signed? It might be part of the signature verification process.

Comment: how do I check that? Edit: No, I didn't use a signtool.

Comment: Try WireShark to see what it actually does. At the very least you should get a domain name. Start with a clean slate by using `ipconfig /flushdns`.

Comment: Brilliant that `WireShark`... I'll troll this little digital fishy.... and report back if its a verification issue or something else unexpected ;-) Cheers for now kichik.

Comment: It worked... cached a tiny fish with the sea-trawler. Now time to analyze what it says ;-)